# What could cause input/output errors after resuming from sleep mode?

Tags: suspend, resume, io

For a few weeks now I experience IO errors when I reopen my Ubuntu (22.04) laptop. Then I can only hold down the power button and hard reset everything. I will gladly provide you with necessary information. I just do not know which commands help to get the important information.

Best regards
Martin